# How to load isotope layout with images perfectly on their position with gaps even before the whole page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

In this example [codepen](http://codepen.io/ableslayer/pen/dporbb), you will see that the boxes kiss each other for a second or two while the page loads and will create the gap (moves to its proper position) just after.

How would it load perfectly on their position and not show the gap even if the page still loads so that you won't see a grid that looks messy without the gap?

I'm using a fixed image height and width with `fitRows`, so I'm assuming that this is possible.

In my example, the unstyled look will only linger for a while because the item is not so many but on the page that I'm working with, I'm displaying so many items that it takes longer to load.

Here's my code:

```
 var $container = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        fitRows: {
          gutter: 10
        }
});

  $container.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $container.fadeIn(1000).isotope('layout');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple solution. Remove the gutter from the layoutmode and put gutter (margins) thru CSS.

http://codepen.io/ableslayer/pen/ORVvpw

```
 var $container = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```

CSS:

```
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```